# Need plugins and themes from clients site

Tags: plugins

I need to grab a clients themes and plugins to migrate their website to our servers.  I tried using All In One Migration but it didnt work and caused some errors.  Now I am going to do a fresh install of Wordpress.  I can get the database with the Migrate DB tool but have no idea how to get the themes or plugins.  I obviously don't have access to FTP or hosting because the current hoster does not want to provide that information to make it easy for us to get the files.  Any suggestions on plugins or methods to get the site files so I can migrate?

Comment: "...the current hoster does not want to provide that information to make it easy for us to get the files." Sounds sketchy to me.

Comment: It is sketchy, the company currently hosting the website does not want to give me access because and I quote "I do not send this information to competitors" so he is not making it easy for us to change the hosting company... dont know what else to do if I cant get access to their FTP or cPanel

Comment: Who is the company currently hosting the site?

Comment: Might be worth asking your client to review their contract with the old host, which I'm assuming is an agency and not a major hosting company, there may be something in there about access during service/contract cancellation.  That said, when I did agency/freelance work, I migrated hundreds of sites from other people and I've never had someone refuse me restricted ftp access or at the very least provide me a tarball of the whole thing, you might try asking for the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without FTP access, if you have an administrative login to the WordPress admin you can grab the code from plugins and themes one file at at time.

For themes go to Appearance > Editor
For plugins go to Plugins > Editor

Select the appropriate theme / plugin and go through the list of files downloading the code, css, etc.

This will not have the images, but you should be able to reconstruct the plugins and themes from this and what is publicly available to download using a website scraping tool... albeit a tedious process.

The best option would be to convince the current host to provide FTP access.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it is my only option; I found lots of plugins that will download and restore but the guy has me blocked so I guess I have to manually do it one file at a time... Get this warning message whenever I try using a plugin to download database, plugins or themes: Warning: php_uname() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/somewhere/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-pclzip.php on line 5672

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the backend to install plugins, you can try to use the plugin backwpup:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/backwpup/

it does a complete backup of your site in a folder or to a cloud-service like dropbox.

Also, it provides an own compression unit so if pclzip is deactivated, you can still use tar ^^